# VueJs with an existing .net core 5 project

Tags: javascript, asp.net, .net, vue.js, asp.net-core

I have a .net core solution containing 9 projects (api/dto/data/service/etc...) 
I need to add a project to work with vuejs framework for the front part using a .net project.
How could i do this pleasee!!!

Comment: just create a an ASP.Net project with VueJS by template, or manually added. Or with Node if you prefer Node than ASP.Net. 
What's the problem ? Microsoft gives you everything you need in Visual Studio and has many tutorials on that topic. 
The question requires much more precision in regards of SO rules, or it will be closed.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you could refer to the [vuejs quickstart](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/javascript/quickstart-vuejs-with-nodejs?view=vs-2019) to know how to create the vuejs project inside the VS.

Then about how to use Vue.js to call API, you could refer to this [cookbook on how to use axios to consume apis](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/using-axios-to-consume-apis.html?redirect=true).